# Dismissing presented UIImagePickerController from UINavigationController view stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

Consider this view controller hierarchy:

```
UIViewController (root)
   - present: UINavigationController
       - push: UIViewController A
       - push: UIViewController B
           - present: UIImagePickerController
```

When dismissing the UIImagePickerController, the UINavigationController pops to it's root view controller (A).

Here's the code to present:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePickerController.mediaTypes = @[ (NSString *)kUTTypeImage ];
imagePickerController.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController: imagePickerController
                   animated: YES
                 completion: nil];
```

I've tried various scenarios and targets for presenting the view controller with the same end result.  Saving/restoring the viewController stack before/after UIImagePickerController dismiss leads to undesirable view transitions.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please show the code that presents and dismisses the UIImagePickerController.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner Updated and also figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

The dismissal works as long as you use UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen modalPresentationStyle.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePickerController.mediaTypes = @[ (NSString *)kUTTypeImage ];
imagePickerController.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController: imagePickerController
                   animated: YES
                 completion: nil];
```